# Ember Data populate records

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Need help getting Ember-Data working with Zend Rest.

At first, I'm familiar with Zend Framework, so the Rest Adapter was easy to setup. Requests by telnet show it works and response also has well-formed HTTP codes.

The setup with Ember Data was a little more complicated. I installed a VM with Ubuntu, installed Ruby 1.9.3, `git clone`ed the ember-data repository and generated the JS file with rake. I also installed the bundler to resolve all dependencies. Seems to work with no errors. 
This was the first time for me. I'm not familiar with ruby.

Unfortuately, it does not appear to be working. On my test app I see with firebug the rest request. The response looks also good. But the object is still empty.

The response:

```
[{"id":"1","user":"testuser","password":"123","mail":"my@me.com","role":"GUEST","active":"1","hash":null,"last_login":null}]
```

response headers:

```
Cache-Control       no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection          Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length      121
Content-Type        application/json; charset=utf-8
Date                Wed, 20 Jun 2012 10:49:38 GMT
Expires             Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive          timeout=15, max=99
Pragma              no-cache
Server              Apache
Vary                Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By        PHP/5.3.13
X-UA-Compatible     IE=Edge,chrome=1
```

My App:

```
    // my script
    App = Em.Application.create();

    App.store = DS.Store.create({
      revision: 4,
      adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({ bulkCommit: false, namespace: 'rest' })
    });

    App.User = DS.Model.extend({
        id: DS.attr('number'),
        user: DS.attr('string'),
        password: DS.attr('string'),
        mail: DS.attr('string'),
        role: DS.attr('string'),
        active: DS.attr('number'),
        hash: DS.attr('string'),
        last_login: DS.attr('date')
    });

    App.postsController = Em.ArrayController.create({
        content: App.store.findAll(App.User)
    });


    // my html page
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
        {{#each App.postsController}}
           <li>{{user}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </script>
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm not sure my ember-data.js is working.

Comment: At first sight, you don't need to declare the id attribute in the User model.

Comment: I remove the id attribute desclartion but no effect. I test now the rest interface by $getJSON inside controller by pushing the data into ember model. That work fine, and the data is populated. 
But i would like to work with the Ember Data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/132

DS.RESTAdapter requires a root element. Such as:

```
{
  users: [{
    "id":"1",
    "user":"test user",
    "password":"123",
    "mail":"my@me.com",
    "role":"GUEST",
    "active":"1",
    "hash":null,
    "last_login":null
  }]
}
```

This is because DS.RESTAdapter supports side loading. Unfortunately, it is not configurable. The only way around this requirement is to roll your own adapter.

Comment: 44 sec faster than me ;). I think this answer is fine :) so +1

Comment: Mille grazie. Search the whole day on this issue and do not found it.